# can't create foreign key in sqlite

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite

I'm trying to run this code in sqlite:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, page varchar(10), dp_record_id integer, foreign key (webserver_id) REFERENCES target_dp(id));
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> Error: unknown column "webserver_id" in foreign key definition

Here's the parent table:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE target_dp(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, server_name varchar(255), location_code varchar(10), active bit(1));
sqlite>
```

I can't see where my syntax error is. 
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a webserver_id column in the TEST table.

```
CREATE TABLE test(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT
                , page varchar(10)
                , dp_record_id integer
                , webserver_id integer
                , foreign key (webserver_id) REFERENCES target_dp(id));
```

Works just fine.

Comment: You can also use the compact syntax: `webserver_id integer REFERENCES target_dp(id)`